# Transform jsp to java code

Tags: java, jsp, web, jsp-tags

I need java code for this jsp line code.
I know how to make it for scope "page" or `"application"` but i really dont know how it works with `"session"`

```
<jsp:useBean id=”pera” class=”beans.User” scope=”sesion”>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Solution.

beans.User user = null;

```
synchronized (application) {

  user = (beans.User) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("user", 
PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

  if (user == null){

    user = new beans.User();

    _jspx_page_context.setAttribute("user", user, 
PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

  }

}
```